# Convert 2d tabular data entries into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JS array:

```
var arr = [["Ashley","2017-01-10",80],
       ["Ashley","2017-02-10",75],
       ["Ashley","2017-03-10",85],
       ["Clara","2017-01-10",90],
       ["Clara","2017-02-10",82]];
```

and want to make a new array with nested objects. The idea is to have the name, period and score in the new objects. It should look like this:

```
var newArr = [{"name":"Ashley", "2017-01-10":80, "2017-02-10":75, "2017-03-10":85},
              {"name":"Clara", "2017-01-10":90, "2017-02-10":82}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use a plain-JS object as a map to temporarily store the objects by their associated human name as you iterate through your `array`:

```js
var array = [
  ["Ashley", "2017-01-10", 80],
  ["Ashley", "2017-02-10", 75],
  ["Ashley", "2017-03-10", 85],
  ["Clara", "2017-01-10", 90],
  ["Clara", "2017-02-10", 82]
]

var result = []
array.reduce(function(map, e) {
  map[e[0]] || result.push(map[e[0]] = { name: e[0] })
  map[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2]
  return map
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the name and collect the other data with it.

```js
var array = [["Ashley", "2017-01-10", 80], ["Ashley", "2017-02-10", 75], ["Ashley", "2017-03-10", 85], ["Clara", "2017-01-10", 90], ["Clara", "2017-02-10", 82]],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a[0]]) {
                hash[a[0]] = { name: a[0] };
                r.push(hash[a[0]]);
            }
            hash[a[0]][a[1]] = a[2];
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```